# How to cut discord js messages longer than 2000 at a specific point?

Tags: javascript, discord, message, long-integer

I've been working on a Discord bot and one of my functions is that it sends a channel message which can be longer than 2000. I've managed to cut it into chunks and send it to a channel but the problem is that it cuts my message at random points and it destroys text formatting. Can I do it to cut message close to 2000 but for instance only at point when it ends at "\n" so text formatting is still intact?

Here's message split function:

```
function splitMessage(str, size) {
    const numChunks = Math.ceil(str.length / size)
    const chunks = new Array(numChunks)

    for (let i = 0, c = 0; i < numChunks; ++i, c += size) {
        chunks[i] = str.substr(c, size)
    }

    return chunks
```

And here's displaying my message (which may vary on data that it gets from database)

```
        const players = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(query));
        let darkPlayers = [];
        let redPlayers = [];
        let whitePlayers = [];
        players.forEach(player => {
            if (player.inside== dark){
                darkPlayers.push([`${player.inside} Player name: **${player.name}**`]);
            } else if (player.inside == red) {
                redPlayers.push([`${player.inside} Player name: **${player.name}**`]);;
            } else if (player.inside == white){
                whitePlayers.push([`${player.inside} Player name: **${player.name}**`]);
            }

        })
        const topInformation = "Below is presented a list, it is automatically updated upon any data entry or removal.\n";
        const darkInformation = `${dark} indicates top.\n`;
        const redInformation = `${red} indicates medium.\n`;
        const whiteInformation = `${white} indicates low.\n`;
        const space = "\n";
        const header = topInformation + darkInformation + redInformation + whiteInformation + space;
        const timestamp = formatDate(new Date());
        const lastUpdated = `*Last update of this list was made on ${timestamp}*`;
        const footer = space + "My bot text" + space + lastUpdated;
        const playersString= darkPlayers.join("\n") + space + redPlayers.join("\n") + space + whitePlayers.join("\n");
        const channelMessageString = header + playersString + footer + lastUpdated;
        const messageChunks = splitMessage(channelMessageString, 1900)
        const splitted = splitString(channelMessageString);
        for (chunk of messageChunks) {
          await client.channels.cache.get(listChannel).send(chunk);
        }
        
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change up your chunk function to operate on lines instead of individual characters:

```js
const text = `\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ante dolor, consectetur sit amet nisi sit amet, aliquet dignissim tortor. Duis fringilla odio ac eros mollis fringilla. Donec risus sapien, rutrum vel facilisis gravida, dignissim eu nunc. Nunc eleifend at tellus et condimentum. Donec non faucibus urna, at lacinia arcu. Proin vel rutrum magna. Nam hendrerit tortor accumsan sem facilisis faucibus. Donec condimentum arcu aliquam enim mollis fermentum. Aliquam lorem lacus, porta maximus enim a, finibus egestas ligula. Mauris a lectus ultrices magna ultrices accumsan. Praesent auctor sem eu varius condimentum.

Aliquam scelerisque dapibus tellus sed lobortis. Praesent tempor mauris in tristique gravida. Phasellus commodo maximus tempor. Donec luctus dictum mauris, eget vulputate felis bibendum a. Vivamus feugiat pharetra turpis sed gravida. Praesent convallis viverra neque. Nulla id est a enim accumsan posuere non at tellus. Quisque nec sem vel metus tristique suscipit. Integer sed convallis lacus. Sed lorem metus, tempor at tempor eget, porta quis nibh. Proin cursus sed velit et fermentum. Morbi nec risus sed lorem interdum dapibus at sed quam. Nulla pretium eget dui vel euismod. Suspendisse efficitur bibendum felis, et placerat ex. Morbi ut augue id nulla tempus ornare ac a ante.

Curabitur tempor condimentum vestibulum. Curabitur posuere volutpat erat, eget venenatis nisl porttitor vel. Aenean leo quam, varius vel pharetra a, pellentesque in dolor. Nullam finibus feugiat tempor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce elementum dui ut sem feugiat, eu interdum sapien tempor. Praesent ut lobortis velit, ut congue quam. Sed tortor ligula, gravida et lobortis dictum, cursus a arcu. Morbi placerat varius elementum. Phasellus pulvinar at ligula nec rhoncus. Vivamus faucibus lobortis ante, sit amet porttitor erat mollis tempor. Nam mollis, risus id pulvinar porta, nisi erat hendrerit orci, eu finibus ante urna vel purus. Ut sit amet maximus elit, quis placerat massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

Morbi vulputate est id fringilla faucibus. Maecenas libero nisi, ultricies at hendrerit at, semper eu dolor. Nam vehicula sagittis sapien, non gravida quam consectetur at. Cras at arcu mattis, auctor nulla non, gravida urna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi non neque tincidunt, sollicitudin quam et, mattis ipsum. Aenean congue, est sed faucibus vulputate, risus eros condimentum nibh, quis tempor sem velit vitae justo. Suspendisse nec varius ex, quis sagittis lectus. Cras blandit porta lectus, non vehicula urna vestibulum nec. Donec leo nulla, aliquam eu mattis eget, ornare sit amet odio. Donec non mauris vitae felis feugiat faucibus eget congue purus. Integer congue lacus ut nisi consectetur, sed consequat odio ullamcorper. Nam purus leo, lobortis accumsan lobortis condimentum, mattis quis massa.

Nunc consequat nisl ac hendrerit egestas. Etiam a tellus et neque vestibulum euismod nec vulputate eros. Maecenas dui nisl, ultricies eget elit non, blandit egestas ligula. Ut massa quam, lobortis ac lobortis in, fermentum ac sem. Fusce sit amet erat eget leo vehicula lacinia vitae non risus. Integer dignissim cursus arcu posuere vestibulum. Donec rutrum, felis in ornare varius, ipsum lectus accumsan lorem, a ultrices purus ipsum et tortor. Sed ut nibh molestie, laoreet ex sed, scelerisque velit. Aenean id dui eget sapien laoreet semper.
`;

function chunkByLines(text, length) {
    const lines = text.split("\n");
    const chunks = [];
    const chunk = [];
    
    for (const line of lines) {
        if (chunk.concat(line).join("\n").length > length) {
            chunks.push([...chunk].join("\n"));
            chunk.length = 0;
        }
        
        chunk.push(line);
    }

    chunks.push(chunk.join("\n"));
    
    return chunks;
}

console.log(chunkByLines(text, 2000));
```

Comment: Splitting with "\n" actually removes "\n" which destroys formatting as well.

Comment: @damskw Right... I believe joining with `\n` should fix it then?

Comment: it kinda fixed but it didn't catch the whole text, like 3/4 is actually send and the rest is gone.

Comment: @damskw Sorry, I forgot to add the leftovers to the result :p

Comment: All works perfectly! Thanks so much, it saved me lots of headaches! :D